# in Chrome, open new tabs in foreground

Tags: macos, browser-tabs

With OS X, opening a link to a new tab opens in the background (existing tab stays in foreground).  How can I force new tabs in the foreground?

Comment: Do you have the "Chrome Toolbox"-extension installed? This is a setting in its options.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, When asking questions also include anything you have tried so we're not suggesting things that have already failed as @Rik has posted something which should solve this and is the first result in a google search of you title

Answer (score 3):

Try [This Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-to-the-front/hjaooagfdhdhmbfchnkhggjmacjlacla).  It is what I use myself on both Windows and Linux so it should work on OS X too.

Comment: "Tabs to the front" is exactly what I needed.  Works perfectly.

Comment: Right on, if your question is solved be sure to mark an answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Left-Click on the link to open it in the fore ground. This is a work around so go with Rik's suggestion.

Comment: Or in OS X you can hold command and shift instead of control and shift.